# what are all ordered pairs $(a,b)$ for which $17a^2-10ab+2b^2-4a+2=0$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, factoring

what are all ordered pairs $(a,b)$ for which $17a^2-10ab+2b^2-4a+2=0$

I am having a hard time solving this problem.

I started by plugging $a=0$ and $a=b=1$ but that doesn't help. So the answer is not so obvious meaning there is a strategy required however I just dont see it.

I can't factor anything since there is no common factors and that $17$ is being annoying as well.

Any ideas on how to proceed with this problem?

Comment: For fixed $a$ it is a quadratic in $b$. Can you find solutions for $b$ in terms of $a$ then?

Comment: Also, what kind of numbers do you want $a$ and $b$ to be? Integers?

Comment: All ordered pairs from what set?

Comment: The problem is that annoying $10ab$-term, and by making a substitution $a=A+\lambda b$, you get an equation in $A$ and $b$ which, for a good choice of $\lambda$, no longer has the $Ab$-term. Then you can complete squares and get something of the form $17(A-h)^2+c(b-k)^2=d$, where, if I’m not mistaken, $c=9/17$ and $d$ is negative. So no solutions.

Answer (score 1):

If we write 
$$17a^2-a(5b+2)+2(b^2+1)=0$$
the quadratic formula still applies.

Therefore

$$b=\frac{10\pm \sqrt{100a^2-8(17a^2-4a+2)}}{4}$$

$$=\frac{1}{2}\left( 5a\pm\sqrt{-9a^2+8a-4} \right)$$

However, $-9a^2+8a-4<0$ so there are no real solutions, but infinitely many complex ones.